# Asynchronous methods vs threads

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, unity-game-engine, async-await

All the C# coding I do is compiled in Unity, which unfortunately means that I am compiling against 10 year old C# 2-.NET 2.0!
There are many new features introduced in C# 4,5 and 6 I would really like to start implementing in my code. Recently came across this 'hack' which apparently allows support of most of these features.
https://bitbucket.org/alexzzzz/unity-c-5.0-and-6.0-integration/src

Along with AsyncBridge even Async methods are supported.
https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/asyncbridge-write-async-code-for-net-3-5/

As an async-thread novice my question is, are Async methods in general preferable to threads and can threads be replaced using Async methods in most cases?

Comment: Async methods are run on threads. I don't think they can be compared directly.